# How to retreive all lead fields from salesforce?

Tags: api, php

Hi I am using salesforce Enterprise api to add leads in salesforce.

```
    $SFDCUSERNAME = "myusername";
    $SFDCPASSWORD = "mypassword!";
    $SFDCSECURITY_TOKEN = "mytoken";
    $SFDCCLIENT = "soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php";
    $SFDCWSDL = "soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml";

require_once($SFDCCLIENT);

try {
    $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
    $myConnection = $mySforceConnection->createConnection($SFDCWSDL);
    $myLogin = $mySforceConnection->login($SFDCUSERNAME, $SFDCPASSWORD.$SFDCSECURITY_TOKEN);


}
catch(Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

I can create leads using api. 
Now I want to retrieve all fields which are available to a lead in salesforce(not only the custom fields but also the default/in_built fields) and show it in a HTML drop down field.

Is it possible to retrieve all fields of a lead using salesforce api? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I got an answer and it worked for me. I am posting it here , hoping it may be helpful to someone some other time.

```
try {
        $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
        $myConnection = $mySforceConnection->createConnection($SFDCWSDL);
        $myLogin = $mySforceConnection->login($SFDCUSERNAME, $SFDCPASSWORD.$SFDCSECURITY_TOKEN);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($mySforceConnection->describeSObject('Lead'));
        echo "</pre><br>";       

    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }
```

There is a function in salesforce api `describeSObject()` which outputs the complete details about the object including the field details.

**[REFERENCE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Samples)**